# How do I figure out the type of the SQL Server 2008 R2 View definition

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

I was walking view definitions in a database today using sqlalchemy 0.6 (using get_view_definition()) and I ran across one that was larger than 4000 characters.  MS seems to say ([Information Schema Views for VIEWs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181381.aspx)) that shouldn't be returned.  MS SQL Server Management Studio shows the whole thing (well at least the beginning and the end look right) if you ask for the design of the view.  sqlalchemy returns a string truncated at 4000 characters (boo, hiss).  How can I ask the database what type it wants to return for this piece of data instead of depending on what I suspect is out of date documentation.  I'm assuming the type is probably varchar.  I would just like to verify that.

Comment: Those are only the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. Are you sure that's what sqlalchemy uses? It's certainly not what SSMS uses.

Comment: Thank you Remus and John for your responses.  If you look at the SQL generated  by sqlalchemy (.6, having tried a .7 rev yet) it is using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views.  I question its choice to return busted data.  But now I have a way to work around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object definitions, including view definitions, can be retrieved from the [`sys.sql_modules`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx) view, or using the [`OBJECT_DEFINITION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176090.aspx) function. This includes the proper `NVARCHAR(MAX)` type that contains the untruncated definition of the object.

Other backward compatibility views like [`sys.syscomments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293.aspx) or [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181381.aspx) contain a column of type `NVARCHAR(4000)` and such a type, by definition, must truncate the object definition after first 4k characters. Many cross platform tools will rely on the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views and perhaps sqlalchemy does the same.